# Is there a way to write this out in a better way? I want to get rid of an Iverson bracket

Tags: discrete-mathematics, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I have $\lceil \frac{m+1}{1.37}\rceil - \lceil \frac{m}{1.37}\rceil$ which I think could be written as $[m + 1$ is an integer not divisible by 1.37$]$, where [] denotes the Iverson bracket.

I want to know if there is a better way of writing this by working with the ceilings or if I should leave it like this.

Comment: You've phrased this backwards I think - you want to know if the ceiling function of $ m $ is equivalent to the statement in the brackets, which you had first.

Comment: And, if it is, write it out without the ceiling

Comment: "Better" is a value judgement, however, $\lceil m+1 - 1.37\lceil m/1.37\rceil\rceil$ does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missing something key here, these are not well-defined, much less equivalent...

[m is an integer divisible by 1.37] is not even a proper statement to take a truth value of, I should believe. "1.37" is a representation most specifically of the rational number $ \frac{137}{100} $, where "divibility" isn't testable in any meaningful way. You just can't divide by 0.

Integer divisibility, $ m | n $, for $ m, n \in \mathbb{Z} $, is defined as being true iff the statement $ n = mq $ is true. This is not possible with a rational number.

As for the ceiling function, it can be 1: try $ m = 1 $. So I would say this is false at best, and nonsense at worst.

Comment: Would the statement "$m +1$ is an integer and $\frac{m+1}{1.37}$ is not an integer" work? I edited the question a little bit but by divisible I meant the quotient yields an integer

Comment: @FranciscoJoséLetterio "by divisible I meant the quotient yields an integer" ... all right, let's play the "mathematicians are stupid" game - what's a quotient?
Typically, the poorly named division algorithm gives you that for any integers $ a, b $, we can find unique integers $ q, r $, $ 0 \leq r < b $ such that $$ a = bq + r $$ holds. Then the quotient is q... but a rational number division doesn't have a quotient in the divisibility sense, only a quotient as a result of dividing, which is an integer when the two can be written similar to my answer.